# Possible to step-through the release-versions of new() and malloc() in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

When I debug in Visual Studio it will hapilly allow me to step-in to the debug implementations of `malloc()` and `new()`. However, when I step-through the code in release mode it seems to miss these functions entirely :s

I don't care whether its from Debug or Release, but is there a way I can step-in to the actual non-debug/release versions of `malloc()` and `new()` in Visual Studio? Is there just a setting I need to change in the property settings?

This can be for VS 2012 or 2013.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's because symbols aren't provided for the release version of the library.  You could step into the functions at the assembly level (but that might not be too helpful).  Also, the source for most of the library is provided (excluding much of the math library functions) - you might be able to build enough of it in release mode with symbols to get whatever information you need.  But I wouldn't be surprised if it takes a fair bit of work to build enough of the library to allow you to compile your program to link against your build.

Comment: Would you/anyone know the location of new() and malloc() in the Microsoft runtime? I couldnt find it from searching using fileseek.

Comment: There's almost nothing to step through.  `new` calls `malloc` which calls `HeapAlloc`.  There's a loop in `new` to invoke the new handler as is required by the standard.  Otherwise, that's all there is...